# Pass a pointer to an array of pointers to a C struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct Image {
    byte height;
    byte width;
    byte data[];
} Image;
```

and I create 2 images:

```
static const __flash Image GRID = {
    .width = 16,
    .height = 8,
    .data = {
        0x10, 0x10, 0x28, 0x28, 0x44, 0x44, 0x82, 0x82, ...
    }    
};

static const __flash Image HOUSE1 = {
    .width = 24,
    .height = 24,
    .data = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, ...
    }
};
```

Then I create an array of pointers to the images:

```
static const __flash Image *IMAGES[] = {
    &GRID,
    &HOUSE1,
};
```

I can draw an image using my `draw_image()` function:

```
void main(void)
{
    draw_image(IMAGES[0], 16, 16);
}
```

I have a map:

```
typedef struct Map {
    word cols;
    word rows;
    byte tiles[];
} Map;

static const __flash Map level_1 = {
    .cols = 16,
    .rows = 8,
    .tiles = {
        0,0,1,0,...
```

the `.tiles` field is a list of indexes into the `IMAGES` array. I'm doing it this way because my engine doesn't know what images are available without being told:

```
void draw_map(const Map __memx *map, const Image __memx *tileset[]);
{
    ...
    draw_image(tileset[map->tiles[index]], x, y);
    ...
}
```

called thusly:

```
void main(void)
{
    draw_map(&level_1, &IMAGES[0]);
}
```

The compiler does not like this and gives me incompatible pointer type warnings. The map is not drawn:

```
note: expected 
‘const __memx Image ** {aka const __memx struct Image **}’
but argument is of type 
‘const __flash Image ** {aka const __flash struct Image **}’
```

I did try removing the `[]` from the `draw_map()` declaration:

```
void draw_map(const Map __memx *map, const __memx Image *tileset);
```

but that gave me an error in calling the `draw_image()` call:

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘draw_image’
             draw_image(tileset[0], c*8+(64 - r*8), r*8);
                        ^
tile-engine.c:63:6: note: expected 
‘const __memx Image * {aka const __memx struct Image *}’ but argument is of type 
‘Image {aka const __memx struct Image}’
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
void draw_image(const Image __memx *image, int x, int y)
{
    byte rows = image->height>>3;
    byte cols = image->width>>3;

    for(byte r=0 ; r<rows ; r++)
    {
        for(byte c=0 ; c<cols ; c++)
        {
            draw_tile(&image->data[(r*cols+c)*8], &image->data[(r*cols+c)*8], x+(c*8), y+(r*8));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Map ? Where it comes from ?

Comment: Why do you have to declare `draw_map` parameters with `__memx` ?

Comment: @Niloct Sorry, the __flash and __memx are for the compiler - it's an AVR program and the flash program storage and SRAM have different address spaces.

Comment: @bruno sorry, I've added the `Map` typedef, very similar to `Image` really

Comment: Could you provide the definition of `draw_image`?

Comment: Why are you passing variables qualified with `const __flash` to a function which expects its parameters to be qualified with `const __memx`?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn added draw_image

Comment: @dbush `__flash` tells the compiler to keep the data in the flash space and not copy it into SRAM at program start. `__memx` tells the compiler that addresses might be to data in either flash or SRAM. I use it so I have the option to pass computed tiles/images if I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be exactly what the compiler has identified: you are passing a `__flash` pointer to a function that requires a `__memx` pointer.

If you change the signature of draw_map to

```
void draw_map(const Map __memx *map, const Image __flash *tileset[])
```

then it works fine.

Okay, so why is this necessary, when the compiler is okay with accepting a `__flash` pointer for the first argument, which is also defined as `__memx`?

The reason is that the first pointer is passed by value while the second is passed by reference (`tileset` is a pointer to a `__memx` pointer).

According to the AVR documentation, `__flash` pointers are 16-bit pointers into (obviously) flash memory, while `__memx` pointers are 24-bit pointers that can point to locations either in flash or in static RAM.

It looks like the compiler is smart enough to promote a 16-bit `__flash` pointer to a 24-bit `__memx` pointer when passing it by value (similar to how it can promote a 16-bit short to a 32-bit int or long), but it can't cause a 16-bit pointer that's stored in memory (in your `IMAGES` array) to expand to 24 bits.

Since `__memx` pointers are slower to use than `__flash` pointers (apparently the compiler has to check if the actual pointer refers to flash or static RAM and use different instructions for each), if you know your image and map data will always be in flash, just pass `__flash` pointers.

Comment: I had no idea using __memx had such an impact on performance - I changed all of the uses to __flash and went from ~43 ms/frame to ~30. Still a bit on the slow side sadly, but interesting.